# ES6 export global symbol

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am defining a file where I have global resources

```
import winston from 'winston';

const LOGGER_KEY = Symbol.for('loggerKey');

const globalSymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(global);
const hasLogger = (globalSymbols.indexOf(LOGGER_KEY) > -1);

if (!hasLogger) {
  const formatter = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.align(),
    winston.format.printf(
      info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
    ),
  );

  const transportConsole = new (winston.transports.Console)({
    format: formatter,
    level: 'info',
  });

  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
      transportConsole,
    ],
  });

  global[LOGGER_KEY] = logger;
};

export {
  global[LOGGER_KEY] as logger
}
```

}

In ES5 I used to export like this and it worked

```
module.exports = {
  logger: global[LOGGER_KEY],
}
```

but I do not if this is possible in ES6

Comment: You can only export variables in ES6 modules. Just create a `const logger = global[LOGGER_KEY] || …;` and export that.

Comment: Btw, in ES6 you'd use `includes` instead of `indexOf`. But it's even simpler: `hasLogger = LOGGER_KEY in global;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that with ES6, but that's easily resolved by assigning the object property to a variable first:

```
const logger = global[LOGGER_KEY];
export {logger}
```

Comment: Or `export const logger = global[LOGGER_KEY];`

Comment: @Bergi Of course.... that shows you how few ES6 modules I wrote recently 